# srvstart.exe based service start and then shutdown. [win7-64]

Tags: windows, service

I tried to create a service to launch an app as a service with [srvstart.exe](http://rozanski.org.uk/software) using this syntax

```
SC CREATE myapp DisplayName= "myapp" binPath= “srvstart.exe myapp -c E:\Systema\myapp\myapp.ini” start= auto
```

where myapp.ini is

```
[myapp]
startup=”E:\Systema\myapp\myapp.exe”
shutdown_method=winmessage
```

but whenever I try to start the service I get this message

> THE myapp SERVICE ON LOCAL COMPUTER STARTED AND THEN STOPPED.SOME
>   SERVICES STOP AUTOMATICALLY IF THEY ARE NOT IN USE BY OTHER SERVICES
>   OR PROGRAMS

Have I done something wrong? 
Is there any other way to create a simple background service of an exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I just found http://nssm.cc/ and it works seamlessly 
and it's only:

```
nssm install myapp
```

and a nice gui do the rest of the work.

PD: I suspect than srvstart is just for winxp and SC do the work itself (the hard way)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a Windows2012 R2 version and it works ;-)

[How To Create a User-Defined Service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137890)

- Install the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)
- C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Instsrv.exe Notepad C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Srvany.exe
- Run Regedit andn go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
- From the Edit menu, click Add Key.

  > Key Name: Parameters
- Select the Parameters key
- From the Edit menu, click Add Value.

  > > Value Name: Application
  > >     Data Type : REG_SZ
  > >     String : C:\Windows\notepad.exe
- Then start the service :-)